# Erroneous proof involving cartesian products?

Tags: solution-verification

The problem is: prove if A, B, and C are sets and $A \times C = B \times C$, then A = B.

I decided to prove it and wrote this proof:

Proof.  First we will show that if A, B, and C are sets and $A \times C = B \times C$, then $A \subseteq B$.  Assume $(x,y) \in A \times C$.  Thus, $x \in A$ by definition of cartesian product.  Hence, $(x,y) \in B \times C$ by definition of subset (equal sets are subsets of each other).  Consequently, $x \in B$ by definition of cartesian product.  Therefore $x \in A$ implies $x \in B$, so it follows that $A \subseteq B$.

Conversely, we will show that if A, B, and C are sets and $A \times C = B \times C$, then $B \subseteq A$.  Assume $(x,y) \in B \times C$.  Thus $x \in B$ by definition of cartesian product.  Hence $(x,y) \in A \times B$ by definition of subset (equal sets are subsets of each other).  Consequently, $x \in A$ by definition of cartesian product.  Therefore, $x \in B$ implies $x \in A$, so it follows that $B \subseteq A$.

Hence, we have shown that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, so $A = B$.

IS IT CORRECT?

Comment: $\{0\}\times\varnothing=\{0,1\}\times\varnothing$, but $\{0\}\ne\{0,1\}$.

Comment: The error in your proof lies with the line "*Assume $(x,y)\in A\times C$*"  This assumption might not have been valid in the case that $A\times C$ were empty.  If you were to require $A,B,C$ all to be non-empty then your proof would have at a glance been fine.

Comment: You need $C$ not empty for this to be true.